# Is it possible to connect Visual Studio 2013 Express to TFS 2012 Express?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with VS 2012 Express for Web and TFS 2012 Express. Now I want to upgrade the VS, using 2013 express version, but not with TFS, because there are still other project development.

So, is it possible using VS 2013 Express with TFS 2012 Express? Is there any concern? 
You can describe pros and cons if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the body of my answer must be at least 30 characters, so please excuse this unnecessary leading sentence:

Yes.

Comment: no problem, I updated my question if you don't mind you could update your answer so that your answer more than 30 characters :D